# JSON Data format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Not very familiar with JSON data and how to create it using JavaScript.this is what i am trying
i have created two JS variables

```
var json={};
var json1={};
```

i have some certain loops to iterate data and loops like

```
for(firstLoop){
   key=outerKey;
   for(innerLook){
   innerKey=innerkey;
     for(lastloop){
       jsonValues= create values in a java variable
     }
      json[innerKey]=jsonValues;
    }

    json1[outerKey]=JSON.stringify(json);
  }
```

Doing this i am getting following output

```
Required: "{"Center":"radio_Required_Center_0,radio_Required_Center_1,","Left":"radio_Required_Left_0,"}"
```

which is not a valid JSON format.My idea id to create a outer-key say `Required` and than an inner one's in my case `Center` and `Left`

so that i can iterate each value with respect to key `Center` (i can break the string based on `'`)

i am not sure how to create correct structure and i don't want to do it on server side which can be done easily.
any solution or hint will really be helpful.

**Edit**

```
var data= JSON.stringify(json1);
```

giving following output

```
{"Required":"{\"Center\":\"radio_Required_Center_0,radio_Required_Center_1,\",\"Left\":\"radio_Required_Left_0,\"}"}
```

which is valid JSON data, now i need to execute some code based on the data in the JSON and here are my requirements

1. Fetch the outer-key (Required or there can be other also).
2. Fetch all values under the key `Center` and `Left`
3. Create array from the value retrieved from step 2 (split based on ",").
4. Loop through the values obtained from step 3 and execute the logic.

My real challenge is at step number 2 and 3 where i need to fetch the keys and its associated values and those key and not predefined so i can not access  them based on there name.

I am thinking of a way to get key and its values without hard coding key names and execute my logic.
is it possible in by this approach or not?

Answer (score 0):

try [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) to validate your JSON

This is valid:

```
{
    "Center": "radio_Required_Center_0,radio_Required_Center_1,",
    "Left": "radio_Required_Left_0,"
}
```

This is valid too:

```
{
    "Required": {
        "Center": "radio_Required_Center_0,radio_Required_Center_1,",
        "Left": "radio_Required_Left_0,"
    }
}
```

This isn't:

```
Required: {
    "Center": "radio_Required_Center_0,radio_Required_Center_1,",
    "Left": "radio_Required_Left_0,"
}
```

using `JSON.stringify()` is the right way of converting javascript objects to JSON string format. However if you want to put it in a variable you should do that first, later in the last step you convert to JSON string.

```
var output = { "Required": yourpreviousjsonvar },
    jsonString = JSON.strinify(output);
```

**EDIT:**

You need to process the data first you probably won't even need the JSON string if I understand you right. (=> if however you already got a string you need it parsed first. Do it using `JSON.parse(yourjsonstring)`)

1. Fetch the outer-key (Required or there can be other also).
2. Fetch all values under the key Center and Left
3. Create array from the value retrieved from step 2 (split based on ",").
4. Loop through the values obtained from step 3 and execute the logic.

having this as variable:

```
var a = {
    "Required": {
        "Center": "radio_Required_Center_0,radio_Required_Center_1,",
        "Left": "radio_Required_Left_0,"
    }
}
// step 1
console.log(a.Required);
// step 2
console.log(a.Required.Center);
console.log(a.Required.Left);
// step 3
var center = a.Required.Center.split(',');
var left = a.Required.Left.split(',');
// step 4
for(var i = 0; i<center.length; i++){
    console.log("doing somthing with", center[i]);
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/nWJ7x/) => use Chrome/safari/Opera's [developpertools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview#access) and check the console to check the output. Or use firebug (in firefox) Or IE9 or greater (F12).

Comment: Thanks for the input, i some how not put my problem correctly.Please see my updated post

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a modern version of Javascript, it comes with JSON functions built-in.

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsobject);
```

...to convert a JS object into a JSON string.

(See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

and

```
var jsOject = JSON.parse(jsomString);
```

...to convert back in the other direction.

(see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

The only time you need to worry about this not being built-in is if you're using an old browser - for example, older versions of IE. However, in this case, there are polyfill libraries like [this one](http://www.json.org/js.html) that you can load which will implement the above syntax for you.

Comment: Not well supported natively, the current recommendation is to use JSON2 as this detects for native support and if not parses it itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use native Javascript toSource :

```
var obj= new Object();
var obj1= new Object();

for(firstLoop){
   key=outerKey;
   for(innerLook){
   innerKey=innerkey;
     for(lastloop){
       jsonValues= create values in a java variable
     }
      obj.innerKey=jsonValues;
    }

    obj1.outerKey=obj;
  }

  json = obj.toSource();
  json1 = obj1.toSource();
```

Comment: `toSource()` is gecko (firefox) only! Not supported on Webkit(Chrome, Safari, Opera, nearly all mobile,...) or Internet Explorer. I think it is not a good idea to use this method...

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to compose one big JSON object, you don't need to stringify one JSON object before adding it to another... So instead of doing `JSON.stringify(json)` you can just do `json1[outerKey]=json`

```
for(firstLoop){
   key=outerKey;
   for(innerLook){
   innerKey=innerkey;
     for(lastloop){
       jsonValues= create values in a java variable
     }
      json[innerKey]=jsonValues;
    }

    json1[outerKey]=json;
  }
```

Comment: i am able to create a valid JSON but not sure how to parse it to get values so that i can run my logic

Comment: Where do you need to parse it? In JavaScript or in something like C#? JSON is just an object. So you can directly access its properties, its properties' properties, ... Can you show some code you're using when trying to parse it?

Comment: i need to parse it on JSP page,even i am creating it on the jsp page itself.regarding keys they are dynamic and not static so i can not access them based on fixed key set.I have heard about `Jquery.parseJSON()`, not sure how relevant it is.

Comment: I think you need to rework your question and add more relevant code. What you asked in your comment here is not at all obvious from your original question.